Building a C# equivalent of the SQL Server construct IN?
Often in SQL Server, I use IN to check if a value is in a list of items, for example:
WHERE @x IN (1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13)

I've got as close as I can by defining the following in a library function, thus:
public static bool IIN(object oValue, params object[] oValues)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= oValues.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        if ((oValue.ToString()) == (oValues[i].ToString())) 
           return true;
    }

    return false;
}

I can call that function like thus:
bool bItemFound = IIN(x, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13);

However, because it is in a library, I end up having to reference the library, thus:
bool bItemFound = MyProject.Common.Helpers.CoreHelper.IIN(x, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13);

This really clutters the code. I've tried declaring a lambda function thus at the top of my calling class:
Func<object, params object[], bool> IIN = (a, b) => { return MyProject.Common.Helpers.CoreHelper.IIN(a, b); };

But lambda declarations seem to not like having param arrays. I can make the b parameter an object array, thus:
public static bool IIN2(object oValue, object[] oValues)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= oValues.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        if ((oValue.ToString()) == (oValues[i].ToString())) 
           return true;

    return false;
}

And my lambda declaration is:
Func <object, object[], bool> IIN = (a, b) => { return CoreHelper.IIN2(a, b); };

But then I have to declare an inline throwaway object[] in my calling code:
bool bItemFound = IIN(x, new object[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 });

Is there a neater way of doing this, being as clean and as readable as the SQL equivalent?


This really clutters the code.

If the only goal is to remove this part:
MyProject.Common.Helpers.CoreHelper.

Then a using static directive can do that.  For example, if you include this directive at the top of the file:
using static MyProject.Common.Helpers.CoreHelper;

Then you can call the method directly:
bool bItemFound = IIN(x,1,2,3,5,8,13);


I haven't tested this, but you may even be able to combine it with the global using directive in C# 10:
global using static MyProject.Common.Helpers.CoreHelper;

Which should allow the use of that method throughout the files included in the project.

We're using VS2019, so global is in "Preview" mode, which I think means it is unsupported. However, I wasn't previously aware of using static. This works perfectly. Thank you. Will mark as answer when it lets me.

Asking the question helped me thing about it. The best I have come up with is to write an extension class, thus:
public static class IntExtension
{
    public static bool IsIn(this int x, params int[] values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < values.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            if (values[i] == x) return true;
        return false;
    }
}

In this way I can call it:
bool bItemFound = iMsgType.IsIn(1,2,3,5,8,13);

This feels good enough for me. Would very much welcome other solutions.

What about return values.Contains(x);, as body of the method? You may need to check for null
